# Is there any way to sum (1 to n) and compare it to the sum (n+1 to end of list)?

Tags: python, list, python-3.7

I am trying to do something like comparing sum1 and sum2 as sum1 > sum2 then stop. I am calculating sum1 as iterating from 0 index to n and sum2 by iterating n+1 to the last index but I cannot do that I am getting out of the index error. I tried to solve it by putting some condition but it runs infinite loop. I will be really appreciated if someone can help. Following is the code I wrote. Thank you!! I am using python 3.7

```
intList = [0 2 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 3 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 2 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0]
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0

for i in range(len(intList)):
    sum1 = sum1 + intList[i]
    print("Sum1: " , sum1)
    for n in range(len(intList)):
        sum2 = sum2 + intList[n+1]
        print("Sum2: " , sum2)
        # if n+1 < len(intList):
        #     continue
        # else:
        #     break
```

Comment: Please be more clear about sum1,sum2 and n

Comment: `n` isn't defined, so it's tough to know exactly what you're trying to do. But I don't think you don't need a loop: `sum1 = sum(intList[:n+1]) ` and `sum2 = sum(intList[n+1:])`

Comment: n is the indexes from 0 to 104 for this list

Comment: This code defines ``n`` to be any valid index of ``intList``. By definition, ``n + 1`` *must* contain an invalid index, namely one past the end of the list. Please [edit] your post to clearly define what you are trying to do. See the [mcve] and [ask] pages how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage python's inbuilt functions

```
for i in range(len(intList)):
    sum1 = sum(intList[:i+1])
    sum2 = sum(intList[i+1:])
    if sum1>sum2:
      print(i)
      break
```

efficient solution: as moving forward `sum1` will increase and `sum2` will decrease so you can add the current element of the array in `sum1` and subtract from `sum2`

```
sum1 = 0
sum2 = sum(intList)
for i in range(len(intList)):
    sum1 += intList[i]
    sum2 -= intList[i]
    if sum1>sum2:
      print(i)
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

I Guess your logic is little off.  In second loop you are always adding list from index 0 to index [len(intlist)]. Which contradicts your requirement. Instead you want to have value of sum2 as from index intlist[n] to intList[len(intList)]. As for as out of index you are getting because of ’intList[n+1]‘. Below logic should work:

```
sum1 = 0

for i in range(len(intList)):
    sum1 = sum1 + intList[i]
    print("Sum1: " , sum1)
    sum2= 0
    for n in range(i+1,len(intList)):
        sum2 = sum2 + intList[n]
    print("Sum2: " , sum2)
    if sum2 < sum1:
        break
```